# Why isn't the Formik `touched` property being populated?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik

I'm making a form with React, Formik, react-bootstrap, and yup for validation. I am trying to display validation errors, but the `touched` property is not being populated with the fields.

```
const schema = yup.object({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  email: yup
    .string()
    .email()
    .required(),
});

const ChildForm = props => {
  const { child: { name = '', email = '' } = {} } = props;
  const submitHandler = ({name, email}) => console.log(name, email);

  return (
    <Formik
      validationSchema={schema}
      onSubmit={submitHandler}
      initialValues={{ name, email }}
      render={({ handleSubmit, handleChange, values, touched, errors }) => 
      {
        console.log('touched: ', touched);
        return (
          <Form noValidate className="mt-4" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Row>
              <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="name">
                <Form.Label>Full Name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  name="name"
                  required
                  value={values.name}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  isValid={touched.name && !errors.name}
                  isInvalid={touched.name && errors.name}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Your child's name"
                />
                <Form.Control.Feedback>Looks good!</Form.Control.Feedback>
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                  {errors.name || 'Please enter your child\'s name'}
                </Form.Control.Feedback>
              </Form.Group>
            </Form.Row>
            <Form.Row>
              <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="email">
                <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  name="email"
                  required
                  value={values.email}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  isValid={touched.email && !errors.email}
                  isInvalid={touched.email && errors.email}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Your child's email address"
                />
                <Form.Control.Feedback>
                  No spam, we promise!
                </Form.Control.Feedback>
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                  {errors.email || 'Please enter a valid email address'}
                </Form.Control.Feedback>
              </Form.Group>
            </Form.Row>
            <Form.Row className="float-right">
              <Button variant="success" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                <Icon icon={faSave} />
                &nbsp; Submit
              </Button>
            </Form.Row>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? The `console.log(touched)` always shows an empty object.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

@djheru Your solution is correct because Formik sets `touched` flags on `blur` event instead of on `change`. [Here](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/pull/737#issuecomment-402869535) is Formik author comment about this:
You have to call Formiks `handleBlur` to notify Formik that `blur` event has been triggered - so yes, these handlers are needed.

Answer (score 43):

I got it working by accessing the `handleBlur` function that's passed in the `render` function argument, and adding that as an `onBlur` handler for each of the form elements. Not sure if that's needed because I'm using react-bootstrap form components, but the react-bootstrap docs have a Formik example, but the `touched` object was not getting updated.

```html
(
  <Formik
    validationSchema={schema}
    onSubmit={submitForm}
    initialValues={{ name, email }}
    render={({
      handleSubmit,
      handleChange,
      handleBlur, // handler for onBlur event of form elements
      values,
      touched,
      errors,
    }) => {
      return (
        <Form noValidate className="mt-4" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Row>
            <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="nameControl">
              <Form.Label>Full Name</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                name="name"
                required
                value={values.name}
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur} // This apparently updates `touched`?
                isValid={touched.name && !errors.name}
                isInvalid={touched.name && errors.name}
                type="text"
                placeholder="Your child's name"
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback>Looks good!</Form.Control.Feedback>
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {errors.name || 'Please enter your child\'s name'}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>
          </Form.Row>
```

Comment: You saved me a lot of trouble! Can you believe it, the official Bootstrap-React tutorial that shows how to validate forms with Formik is incorrect, and doesn't have this detail! https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation-libraries

Comment: Thank you for the code example. That puts this answer over the selected answer.