# React-Bootstrap Example with Formik marks all error fields (even untouched) in Official Tutorial

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik

In the Bootstrap-React Tutorial, I was reading the section on Form Validation, where they hook up Formik to demo their form validation:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation-libraries

But if you notice in their demo, if you just touch one required field (e.g. "State") and start typing, **all** the form fields immediately are flagged as errors, even the ones you didn't touch.

I noticed they were doing `isInvalid={!!errors.username}` on the last several fields. Their FirstName/lastName use a different strategy: `isValid={touched.lastName && !errors.lastName}`. To test that, I made the initial values blank for FirstName/LastName,

```
      initialValues={{
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
```

to verify that they would flag on touched-only. But it stopped working, and doesn't flag required errors at all now. When I edit firstName/lastName to be blank, there's no error flagged, even though rules are defined on them:

```
  firstName: yup.string().required(),
  lastName: yup.string().required(),
```

The full code is on that page, this is just a snippet:

```
function FormExample() {
  return (
    <Formik
      validationSchema={schema}
      onSubmit={console.log}
      initialValues={{
        firstName: 'Mark',
        lastName: 'Otto',
        username: '',
        city: '',
        state: '',
        zip: '',
        terms: false,
      }}
    >
      {({
        handleSubmit,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        values,
        touched,
        isValid,
        errors,
      }) => (
        <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Row>

        <Form.Group as={Col} md="4" controlId="validationFormik02">
          <Form.Label>Last name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            name="lastName"
            value={values.lastName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            isValid={touched.lastName && !errors.lastName}
          />                  

            <Form.Group as={Col} md="3" controlId="validationFormik04">
              <Form.Label>State</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="State"
                name="state"
                value={values.state}
                onChange={handleChange}
                isInvalid={!!errors.state}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {errors.state}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group as={Col} md="3" controlId="validationFormik05">
              <Form.Label>Zip</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="Zip"
                name="zip"
                value={values.zip}
                onChange={handleChange}
                isInvalid={!!errors.zip}
              />
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found the answer: they don't have the necessary line

```
onBlur={handleBlur} /* This is necessary for 'touched' to be populated! */
```

on each control. The Blur handler is necessary for Formik to populate `touched` values. Their original code isn't populating `touched` properly.

[Why isn't the Formik `touched` property being populated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385931/why-isnt-the-formik-touched-property-being-populated)